# Usage of "better prepare" in a headline

Tags: word-choice

At work we use the headline "Better Prepare for a career in xyz" to mean something to the effect of "Help yourself better prepare for a career in xyz". I feel that the statement is way harsh and comes across as "better prepare for a career in xyz ... or else".

Can someone give me a nerdy sounding reason why this is wrong?

Or ... am I wrong for thinking it is wrong.

Comment: Ask them if they were in the hospital, would they want a card that says "Better Get Soon!"

Comment: I think you're just mistakenly conflating this usage with the perhaps more familiar injunction *"You had better [do such-and-such]"*, which does indeed imply "or else dire consequences will ensue". In this usage, "better" simply means "more effectively". (I hope this explanation isn't too "nerdy"! :)

Comment: ...whatever - it's "general reference". Or peeving.

Comment: I think "conflating" hits the right "nerdy" note there. Basically.

Comment: I guess I've been listening to a lot of ice cube which is why I'm confused. Thanks all!

Comment: It is just lacking a "How to" in front

Comment: @JeffSahol: Dang! You're right! Shoulda said "mixing up"! Nerdiness will out, as they say (well, prolly they don't yet, but I'm sure that'll become a standard aphorism eventually).

Comment: (How to better check yourself before you wreck yourself)

Comment: I'd take it as "Better prepare ... or you will face unpleasant consequences." The idiom can be a threat, but it can also be a warning, i.e. not that I'm going to inflict some punishment on you if you don't follow my directions, but some natural force or a third party might do you harm. If you mean "here's how to do it better", you probably should say "Better preparation for ..." or as mplungjan suggests, "How to better prepare for ...", etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Better prepare for a career in xyz.* It's not the most elegant, but it's also not wrong.

**Better** is being used as an adverb to modify the subjunctive verb **prepare**. The subjunctive mood is used to express anything hypothetical or anticipated:  wish, possibility, opinion. It often appears in company slogans: they suggest *x* will happen if you use their product or service. Another example of a slogan that uses a subjunctive verb with the adverb **better** is WalMart's: *Save Money, Live Better.* 
Often the subjunctive mood is confused with the imperative mood (i.e. a command), possibly because they share a terseness, or sometimes a lack of subject, and both express something that has yet to happen. It's likely that you feel the example sentence is "wrong" because you are simply reading it in the imperative mood. Adding a few more words to our example may help demonstrate the difference:

- Subjunctive: *(Follow these tips to)* better prepare for a career in xyz.
- Imperative: *(You should)* better prepare for a career in xyz *(or  else)*.

My opinion is that confusing-yet-grammatically-sound sentences represent failure to communicate an idea and should be avoided.